# Setting comment box size or style (font size) in comment?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is it possible now to define size of comment box generated with PHPExcel? Or to define its style?

Answer (score 12):

The `width` and `height` can be changed using `setWidth` and `setHeight` commands, as follows:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment("A1")->setWidth("400px");

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment("A1")->setHeight("250px");
```

Answer (score -1):

The comment content can be styled using rich text runs; but the box itself cannot be styled or resized using PHPExcel

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible with php spreedsheet :

`    $spread->getActiveSheet()
     ->getComment('G1')->getText()->createTextRun('Hello World!);

```
$spread->getActiveSheet()
->getComment("G1")->setHeight("400px");
$spread->getActiveSheet()
->getComment("G1")->setWidth("400px");`
```